# Websphere Single Sign-On of JSF applications

Tags: java, jsf, websphere, single-sign-on, josso

i have one application which is in java and for front end we are using JSF. and java bean .. and for back end as AS400 DB2.. so in this application we have one logging page(login.jsf), currently we are using this page for login to the application, so here i want to implement the Single sign on... so if there any best way please suggest me..

Comment: Do you want to use an Active Directory, Lotus Domino or some other LDAP? Or do you want to use your own logic?

Comment: @Udo i want to use some other LDAP

Comment: What do you exactly mean by SSO? Create one token (cookie) available to other sites as well or just reuse an existing user directory?

Comment: @Home i think U know what is SSO.. and m not getting wht you are trying to say..

Comment: @vinod: Yes, but as I wrote I was not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Home Actually first time i am implementing SSO, so i am also not aware about all the things what i explained in the Question that's all i know about my environment and m trying to implement things which you guys suggesting me

Comment: Vinod, I think @Udo provided all you need, just read through the documentation. I know it's not that funny :-)

Comment: yes Home that document is somewhat like R & D work.. and i am reading what Udo is given..

Comment: @vinod its really some R & D, if you haven't done it before you will likely need 2 weeks or more...

Comment: @UDO I am not aware about LDAP too :( if u have good link how to do LDAP setup then please let me know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on want kind of SSO you want to do.

Usually you want to have your users in a central registry like an Active Directory.

Therefor you usually configure the LDAP server within WebSphere. Afterwards you configure your application to use HTTP_BASIC authentication.

EDIT:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4192.html (a little bit outdated, but should show most required steps)

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/SG246316.html

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftsec_msso.html (SSO via LTPA)

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fcsec_SPNEGO_explain.html (SSO via SPNEGO)

The best idea is probably to have a look at the Red Books, search in the Info-Center and bug the IBM support with some PMRs until you got it running. :)

You have to setup your LDAP as a federated repository, enable SSO and secure your application with JAAS.

Comment: I almost downvoted this, but this could work. Besides Active Directory you could use any other LDAP complaint tool too. For something more secure, you could use something that supports SAML.

Comment: @Gerbrand this the standard way we are doing our SSO. As long as the OP doesn't tell what we intends to do I however won't search for the links on how to do it. :)

Comment: Minor update: I said 'almost' down-voted, the above solution is simple and not more complex then needed for both developers and end users, so it has my vote.

Answer (score 1):

check the [JOSSO - Java Open Single Sign-On Project](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home).